# Best way to store quiz questions and answers? Multiple choice of 4 only 1 being correct

Tags: mysql

I want to build a quiz app for family and friends nothing too big, that has the question and 4 answers only 1 being right. I need help to find the best way to store these in a database, so far I've thought of:

1. | Question | Answer | Wrong 1 | Wrong 2 | Wrong 3 |

If I store it like this I feel I can't randomise the answers when displaying back to the app but seems like the most effective way to store lots of data.

2. Two tables:

   **Table 1** | ID | Question |

   **Table 2** | Question ID | Answer | Correct |

I think I've overlooked a lot of ways to do this properly and some help would be gratefully appreciated. I'll be using MYSQL and PHP to retrieve data. Can I store correct answers in 1 database and wrong in another. My only worry is that if I have a lot of questions I will have 4 times as many rows in the answers Table or won't this matter

Comment: sure you can you get an arry back and that you can sort as you like

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm asking which is the best way to store the data. Do you mean an array from my 1st example?

Comment: both are ok, the first is faster, as you don't need to join the tables. But to be honest, you probably will change the design as you go on with your app

Comment: Do second one, else you get redundant data.